# Uncaught exception while doing my first project with zend framework2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am getting following fatal error and warnings in zend framework 2 as described in their website and this is my first time with zend fraework (as well as zend fraework 2). those are---

```
1.Warning: include(F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\module\Album/config/module.config.php):
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-
tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 26

2. Warning: include(): Failed opening 'F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-
tutorial\module\Album/config/module.config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-
tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 26

3. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' 
with message 'Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. boolean given.' 
in F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener.php:317 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener.php(127): 

Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->addConfig('Album', false) 

#1 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->onLoadModule(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #2 F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-
tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468)
: call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207)

: Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerLis in F:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-
tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener.php on line 317
```

i am trying for 4 days, searching for solution in web, but could not found any... i tried doing from the first several times but no solution yet........ please any one help.............?

Comment: this is my module.config.php (module/album/config/) file looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Module.php` file of your Album module, there is something along the lines like this:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

This piece tries to include a file relative to the `Module.php` file. If the module class is under zf-tutorial\module\Album, it includes the file zf-tutorial\module\Album\config\module.config.php.

The only thing I am unsure of is the path. Windows uses `\` as separator, but in the code there is a `/`. This results in a path `zf-tutorial\module\Album/config/module.config.php`.

So check a) do you have this file (config/module.config.php) and b) if that's the case, does it work when you replace the `/` with `\`?

Comment: Can you answer question a too?

Comment: Can you post what's in that file?

Comment: I think your module.config.php is empty, and that is does NOT have `return array();` inside it. Is that correct? Please add `return array()` in it as it might be an empty file.

Comment: no, it is not empty, this is the code in that file....   http://pastebin.com/b0zFkN8y

Comment: Well, there is clearly something wrong between those lines there. The include in the module class returns false, so anywhere between inclusion and parsing there is something wrong. Not sure though, are you sure the file is named correctly? Can you code things like `file_exists()` etc before the include statement?

Comment: i edited the getConfig() as you have told in Module.php and 

public function getConfig() {
          if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php'))
          return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }

now getting this error---  http://pastebin.com/YRTPcS76

Comment: i have found out the problem............ during naming the module.config.php file my IDE ignored the .php extension after the .config